# Scala access sequence of Maps

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, sequence

I have a `IndexedSeq[Map[String, String]]` and I would like to extract value where key is "text" and I would like to put it in a `val text:IndexedSeq[String]`. I have written the following piece but it doesn't work:

```
val text:IndexedSeq[String] = _
for(j <- 0 to indSeq.length-1){
  text(j) = indSeq(j).get("text")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing a compiler error because `indSeq(j).get("text")` returns an `Option[String]`, not a `String`.

If you just want to get all the values for the key `"text"` in a sequence, use:

```
val text = indSeq flatMap (_ get "text")
```

If it's important that the indices of both sequences line up, then you will want to substitute a default value in case the key `"text"` is not present:

```
val text = indSeq map (_.getOrElse("text", "default"))
```

Comment: I am getting the entire map flattened and not just the value that has key "text". So I am looking for "text" -> "Lorem ipsum" and I want a sequence of "Lorem ipsum". I am sure each map has a key "text"

Answer (score 0):

Since you were trying to use a for-comprehension originally, you might also be interested in doing it this way:

```
val text = (for { m <- indSeq } yield m get "text") flatten
```

EDIT

or if you want a default value you could do:

```
val text = for { m <- indSeq } yield m getOrElse("text", "default")
```

Comment: This would get rid of the original indexes, with i understand he's interested in keeping

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is with a for-comprehension with a guard to get rid of the maps that don't have the `"text"` element:

```
val result = for {
  i <- 0 until indexSeq.length
  map = indexSeq(i)
  if map isDefinedAt ("text")
} yield { (i, map("text")) }

val seq = result.toIndexedSeq
```

That way you keep the original indexes with the map. It also avoids holding  any `var` value, which is always a perk